# How to set timer intervals?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to set my countdown timer intervals, so that 1hr = 10minutes (in real time), 1min = 10secs (In real time) and 1s = 0.17s (In realtime) to help when testing my code. I can't seem to find what part of my code to change without causing an error. so I tried defining the interval in the initialise components section and received this:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' timer was null.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Tick += OnTimeEvent;
        DisplayTime();
    }
    private void DisplayTime()
    {
        lblTime.Text = countdownClock.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
    private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Subtract whatever our interval is from the countdownClock
        countdownClock = countdownClock.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));

        if (countdownClock.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
        {
            // Countdown clock has run out, so set it to zero 
            // (in case it's negative), and stop our timer
            countdownClock = TimeSpan.Zero;
            timer.Stop();
        }

        // Display the current time
        DisplayTime();
    }
    private void AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan timeToAdd)
    {
        // Add time to our clock
        countdownClock += timeToAdd;

        // Display the new time
        DisplayTime();

        // Start the timer if it's stopped
        //if (!timer.Enabled) timer.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked) timer.Start();
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "...without causing an error." - could you perhaps edit your post to include this error and where it occurs? I imagine it would be helpful..

Comment: so I tried defining the interval in the initialise components section and received this System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

timer was null.

Comment: The constructor happens before the Load event.  So move all that code to the constructor.

Comment: Acutally it does. THis ihas onthign to do with setting an interval and everything to do with (a9 a failure to know basic debugging and (b) a failure to identify a standard .net error, the null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you introduce a wrapper for your timer. That way you can expose a interval-method that is scaled however you want. For example:

```
public class ScaledTimer : IDisposable
{
    private Timer timer;

    public ScaledTimer() => this.timer = new Timer();
    public void Dispose() => timer.Dispose();
    public void Start() => timer.Start();
    public void Stop() => timer.Stop();
    public double Scale { get; set; } = 1;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => timer.Enabled;
        set => timer.Enabled = value;
    }

    public int Interval
    {
        get => (int)(timer.Interval * Scale);
        set => timer.Interval = (int)(value / Scale);
    }

    public event EventHandler Tick
    {
        add => timer.Tick += value;
        remove => timer.Tick -= value;
    }
}
```

Set Scale to 10 to make the timer tick 10 times as fast. Note that this will not work well if you also use `DateTime.Now` since that will use the actual system time. It might also be a good idea to extract an interface for the timer. This can be useful when unit testing since it allows mocking of the timer. There is also a limited resolution for timers, so it may not work well if the interval is down to ~16ms.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to accomplish (ticking at the same speed, but logically running out your countdownClock at 6x speed), then I believe your best plan of action is to add a constant for time scale.

```
private static readonly int timeScale = 6
```

Then when you adjust your countdownClock in the OnTimeEvent, you can multiply by the scale.

```
countdownClock = countdownClock.Subtract(timeScale * TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));
```

Set your timeScale to 1 to run at normal speed, or to higher values to run faster.

This would give a general idea of how to accomplish your goal, but require hand-editing of the timeScale value when debugging to get your desired behavior.  From here, you can decide how to best manage this - maybe you want to load your timeScale from a config file, or adjust it based on whether #DEBUG is defined.  You may also want to make a countdownClock class that has a Scale property to further encapsulate this behavior.  Final implementation is up to you.

Comment: Sorry, not a very experienced coder but where would I place the private static line. I'm not too sure what you mean by debugging this either. So in addition to the code you provided what else would I need to consider adding as using those two lines alone does not seem to work. Apologies, if this is a stupid question unfortunately my uni course set this coursework with our only lecturer now off absent.